# Firebase auth with password

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Email/Password authentication in firebase is sending email and password in URL. this is a security risk. it is very prone to man in middle attack.

https://auth.firebase.com/v2/testapp/auth/password?&email=aaaa%40pk.com&password=pwd&v=js-2.3.2&transport=json&suppress_status_codes=true

or am i missing something here?

Comment: Cross-post? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/M4-rq_nzCIA

Comment: Also see this topic where one of the engineers answers this specific question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/BBInVuv6JOo/discussion